# What justifies the formula for $e^{a^{\dagger}(f)}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, second-quantization

When studying coherent states, one usually finds the following formula:
$$e^{a^{\dagger}(f)}\Omega = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{\otimes^{n}}}{n!}$$
where $a^{\dagger}(f)$ is the usual creation operator associated with $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ acting on the Fock space $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}(L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3}))$ and $\Omega = (1,0,0,...)$ is the vacuum state.

I want to know: what is the mathematical justification of this formula? Usually, the exponential of a (possibly unbounded) operator is defined by the Spectral Theorem, but in this case one considers *self-adjoint* operators, which is *not* the case for $a^{\dagger}(f)$, which is only symmetric. I believe the answer to my question lies in the concept of analytic vectors, in the following sense.

**Definition:** Let $A$ be an operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ (not necessarily self-adjoint). The set $C^{\infty}(A) := \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}D(A^{n})$ is called the $C^{\infty}$-vectors for $A$. A vector $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(A)$ is called an analytic vector for $A$ if:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\|A^{n}\varphi\|}{n!}t^{n} < \infty$$
for some $t > 0$.

It is easy to see that $\Omega$ is an analytic vector for $a^{\dagger}(f)$. Then, it is reasonable to *define*:
$$e^{a^{\dagger}(f)}\Omega = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a^{\dagger}(f))^{n}}{n!}\Omega,$$
given that the right hand side is convergent. However, this is actually a pretty strange definition, since I am defining an exponential acting on a *single* vector $\Omega$. I would probably need a dense domain here, right? How should I proceed?

Comment: Why can't you define the exponential of $a^*(f)$ on the space of all analytic functions s.t. your penultimate inequality holds?! (I don't know if this is a dense domain, though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only the vacuum, but all vectors containing a finite number of particles (with generally different functions $f$) are analytic for $a(g)^*$.

The space $D$ of finite linear combinations of the previous vectors are analytic as well. This domain is evidently  a linear dense subspace of the Fock space.

$D$ is the common natural dense domain of every $a(g)$ and $a(g)^*$. It is also invariant under the action of these operators, so that the *commutation relations* make sense therein.

You can define the wanted exponential on $D$ using the series. However $D$ is not invariant under the action of these exponentials.

I stress that the proper adjoint operator $a(g)^\dagger$ is defined on a larger domain than $D$,  though the restriction to $D$ of $a(g)^\dagger$ coincides with $a(g)^*$.

The said operators are also closable on $D$.

I suggest Bratteli-Robinson's two-volume textbook on these issues.

Comment: Valter, thanks for your great answer. So, if I pick a vector $\psi = (\psi_{n})_{n}$ with only a finite number of nonzero entries (an element of your set $D$) and apply $a^{*}(f)\psi$ I get a new vector $(f\otimes \psi_{n})_{n}$, which has norm $\|f\|\|\psi\|$ and of course $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n!}\|f\|^{n}\|\psi\|^{n}t^{n}$ converges for every $t$, so every such vector is analytic for $a^{*}(f)$. Did I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. However, I strongly suggest you to consult the book I pointed out to you.